# flex cairngorm addComand not work

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, model-view-controller, flash-builder, cairngorm

Hey everybody) I need help with the understanding of the framework Cairngorm for flex.

I code a simple application slider. I have a main class in which I have a tag

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <control:AppController id="appController" />
</fx:Declarations>
```

Class itself AppController extends FrontController with constructor function:

```
public function AppController()
    {
        addCommand(SliderEvent.BUILD, SliderBuildCommand);
        addCommand(SliderEvent.TRANSITION, SliderTransitionCommand);
    }
```

and finally the code of SliderBuildCommand class:

```
 public function SliderBuildCommand(){}

    public function execute(event:CairngormEvent):void
    {
        config.loadSlides(this);
    }
```

Unfortunately, in debugging, I see that the addition of the command didn't work out. This can be seen if set a breakpoint in "сonfig.loadSlides(this)" line. However, the command (addCommand) is processed.
Any idea why this is happening? Maybe I am a noob and I don't see the obvious :)

Comment: It's been more than 5 years since I last used Cairngorm (this is Cairngorm 2 right?) ... But, to get a command class to run its `execute()` method, you have to dispatch the associated event somewhere. Are you doing that?

Comment: Hmm, not sure about the version of the framework.. I thought cairngorm does this automatically. And which class this should be done?

Comment: There's a big difference between Cairngorm 2 (an actual MVC framework) and Cairngorm 3 (more of a set of recommendations to use various, more modern, MVC frameworks). The fact that you refer to a "front controller" sounds like the old Cairngorm 2. If I recall correctly, in Cairngorm 2 you had to dispatch events (like `SliderEvent.Build`) on the "cairngorm event bus" (AKA Cairngorm Event Dispatcher, or something like that). Google will answer all of this for you ... It's just been too long since I've used it.

Comment: Unless you've inherited a legacy project, learning Cairngorm (2) is a waste of time. Well, in my opinion learning _any_ so-called MVC framework that comes on top of Flex (which already _is_ a proper MV-whatever) is a waste of time (many will disagree with me here), but in terms of added complexity, amount of boilerplate code, intrusiveness and overall architecture, Cairngorm 2 is the worst of them all.

Comment: Here is a link to some great [tutorials on Cairngorm 2 by David Tucker](http://davidtucker.net/articles/cairngorm-tutorials/). I used them back in 2008. Your event classes should be extending the CairngormEvent class, and then you need to dispatch the events with the Cairngorm event dispatcher (still don't remember the right name for it). If you don't do that, your command will never get executed. As @RIAstar and David Tucker mention, Cairngorm 2 is quite outdated in the Flex world as far as MVC frameworks go.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding/mapping commands in `AppController`'s constructor. Declare it in `initialize()` function. Example is given below for your reference.

```
public class AppController extends FrontController
    {
        public function AppController()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function initialize():void
        {
            this.addCommand(SliderEvent.BUILD, SliderBuildCommand);
            this.addCommand(SliderEvent.TRANSITION, SliderTransitionCommand);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then another surprise. initialization initialize () does not happen... Also look at breakpoint. May be the case in some project settings?

Comment: @user2717843 : I am assuming that `AppController` is extending to `FrontController`. If its still not working then try adding `AppController` on **Application** page.

Comment: so I wrote at the beginning of the issue:
"I have a main class in which I have a tag

<fx:Declarations>
    <control:AppController id="appController" />
</fx:Declarations>"